# Logic App > CosmosDB error PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to populate new items from Logic App to CosmosDB, and I ended up with an error 400 *"PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header"*

I did specify the PartitionKey in quotes and still running into the same issue

Can't figure how to make this work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to logic app code view then in "Create or update document" section, try setting `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey` header like:

[image]

Comment: I did this , Now, i have a different error

The partition key supplied in x-ms-partitionkey header has fewer components than defined in the the collection.

Comment: can you paste the value of the header x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, and the full error text?

Comment: I added the partition key as a parameter and its now working